# Python: extract text from string

Tags: python, regex, urlparse

I try to extract text from url request, but not all dict contain key with text, and when I try to use `{k: v[0] for k, v in parse_qs(str).items()}` to urls, I lose a lot of requests, so I try `str = urllib.unquote(u[0])`.
After that I get strings like

```
смотреть лучше не бывает&clid=1955453&win=176
Jade+Jantzen&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=FQB0V9WbIoahsAH5zZGACg
как+скрыть+лопоухость&newwindow=1&biw=1366&bih=657&source=lnms&sa=X&sqi=2&pjf=1&ved=0ahUKEwju5cPJy83NAhUPKywKHVHXBesQ_AUICygA&dpr=1
смотреть лучше не бывает&clid=1955453&win=176
2&clid=1976874&win=85&msid=1467228292.64946.22901.24595&text=как выбрать смартфон
маскаи гейла&lr=10750&clid=1985551-210&win=213
```

And I want to get

```
смотреть лучше не бывает
Jade Jantzen
как скрыть лопоухость
смотреть лучше не бывает
как выбрать смартфон
маскаи гейла
```

Is any way to extract that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split by `&` and take the first part:

```
txt = urllib.unquote(u[0]).split("&")[0]
```

And don't use `str` as a variable name - it's a built-in type name in Python.

**EDIT:**
Unfortunatelly this `2&clid=1976874&win=85&msid=1467228292.64946.22901.24595&text=как выбрать смартфон` line has a different pattern than the others. There's no common way to handle this one together with the others. I was tempted to use regex to match Cyrillic characters but `Jade Jantzen` wouldn't match. So for this one line, where the desired text is at the end, something like

```
txt = urllib.unquote(u[0]).split("=")[-1]
```

would work. Still you didn't provide any actual criteria for desired text. As humans we can say how to transform what you get into what you want from this specific sample. But without clear rules of what to match, we can't provide a complete solution.

*I'm aware that some (again some) of the lines have `"+"` in place of `" "`. This can possibly be solved with `.replace("+", " ")`.*

Comment: and can you say, if string looks like `213&msid=1466344978.51184.22872.22654&text=дэрил диксон`

Comment: I overlooked this one line. There will be no generic way to handle this one together with the others. For this one, the split should happen on `=` and the last part should be taken.